# Find the major products when these cyclohexenone bromides react with caustic potash in alcoholic medium:

Tags: organic-chemistry, halides, hydrocarbons, elimination, tautomer

> Question:

[image]

Also find the order of the rates of the given reactions.

> Answer: The answer of this question is given as option 'D' ie. all products are identical, however I am getting the answer as option 'C'.

> My approach: I figured out that the under the presence of the given reagent the substrates will undergo elimination reaction via the E2 mechanism, in reactions (2) and (3), the same alkenes will be formed and the ketone will tautomerise to form a highly stable phenol, but in the first reaction I made Cyclohex-2,5-dien-one as the product, I am not able to understand how will this covert to phenol?

> For the comparison of the rates I figured out that reaction (2) will have the fastest rate due to a highly acidic hydrogen present (the anion formed is in extended resonance with the double bond and the ketone), however I am not able to compare between the rates of the first and the third reactions.

Am I thinking in the right direction or is there some mistake? Please help.

Comment: @Karl Can you explain by a diagram? I did not get what you wrote.

Comment: Nope, your homework: Draw the detailed step-by-step diagram of the keto-enol step in (2) and (3), then try to do sth. very similar with (1). ;-)

Comment: @Karl thank you , I got the answer as phenol

Comment: Can you comment on the rates of the reactions?

Comment: No clue, honestly. Zilch. But there are others around here who are smarter in OC than me. ;-)

Comment: One of them is probably faster to eliminate than the other two.

Comment: That's obvious textbook mistake - they didn't consider tautomerisation. Still, that should be rather potassium phenolate.

Comment: @user55119 how to we compare between rates of reaction 1 and 3?

Comment: Actually I think this is simple: Tautomerisation comes second, you don't have a particularily strong base, that only works if you can close the aromatic ring at the same time. Bromide is a good leaving group, so I say this is E1, and (1) has the intermediate cation next to the carbonly, that's bad, (3) has the cation next to the double bond, which is OK, but mesomery is not much of an improvement, and (2) is best. ?